# Structural Induction and Induction Hypothesis in Haskell

Tags: haskell, induction

I am trying to prove **'ns'** with the statement below using structual induction. All lists **'ns'** are of type **[Int]** and all **'m'** are of type **Int**.

```
foldl (+) m ns = m + (sum ns)
```

Definitions:

```
sum :: [Int] -> Int         -- summation of an Int list
sum []     = 0              -- s.1
sum (x:xs) = x + (sum xs)   -- s.2

foldl :: (a -> b -> a) -> a -> [b] -> a    -- fold left
foldl _ s []     = s                       -- fl.1
foldl f s (x:xs) = foldl f (f s x) xs      -- fl.2
```

It would be grateful if someone can help me out on this.

Comment: Any thoughts of your own? Anything you've tried? Surely, you have been given some example on how this kind of proof looks in general.

Comment: It seems that your code uses the `my_` prefix inconsistently. You should edit your question to remove them all, I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We would like to prove that for all `ns` and `m`, `foldl (+) m ns = m + sum ns`. We shall proceed by induction on `ns`. In other words, we prove that the property holds for the empty list, and holds for `n:ns` whenever it holds for `ns`.

First, let's see the empty list, and let `m` be an arbitrary number. Our goal is to prove `foldl (+) m [] = m + sum []`. There are many ways to do this, but we will proceed by transforming the left side of the equation into the right side by equational reasoning.

```
foldl (+) m []  -- by definition of foldl
m               -- by right identity of addition
m + 0           -- by the definition of sum
m + sum []      -- QED
```

Now for the `(:)` case. Let our list be `n:ns`. Suppose that the property holds for `ns` for any `m` (this is the induction hypothesis). Our goal is to prove `foldl (+) m (n:ns) = m + sum (n:ns)`. Again, we use equational reasoning.

```
foldl (+) m (n:ns)    -- by the definition of foldl
foldl (+) (m + n) ns  -- by the induction hypothesis, applied to (m + n)
(m + n) + sum ns      -- by associativity of addition
m + (n + sum ns)      -- by the definition of sum
m + sum (n:ns)        -- QED
```

And we're done.

---

A common issue among new students of proof writing is that they're not sure if what they're doing actually makes sense, and this makes them nervous. I recommend taking a look at proof assistants such as [Agda](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php) or [Coq](https://coq.inria.fr/). They are excellent for building proof-writing skill. As a small example of Agda, the above proof can be written very similarly there, with some syntactic differences:

```
-- imports omitted

prop : forall m ns → foldl (_+_) m ns ≡ m + sum ns

prop m [] = begin
  foldl (_+_) m []     ≡⟨⟩ 
  m                    ≡⟨ sym $ +-right-identity m ⟩
  m + 0                ≡⟨⟩
  m + sum []           ∎

prop m (x ∷ ns) = begin 
  foldl _+_ m (x ∷ ns)     ≡⟨⟩
  foldl _+_ (m + x) ns     ≡⟨ prop (m + x) ns ⟩  
  (m + x) + sum ns         ≡⟨ +-assoc m x (sum ns) ⟩ 
  m + (x + sum ns)         ≡⟨⟩
  m + sum (x ∷ ns)         ∎
```

Comment: Is it better to separate the statement `foldl (+) ns = m + sum ns`, into LHS (Left Hand Statement) and RHS (Right Hand Statement) when proving or is it better to prove the statement all together like you have done?

Comment: What do you mean by that? We can transform the left side to the right, or the right side to the left, or both sides to some third expression; the goal is to show that the sides are equal.